# Accessing user's custom field in html.tpl.php

Tags: 7, users

In my html.tpl.php , I was printing this:

```
    print $user->name;
```

which displayed `username`.

But now I need to print Custom field `"First Name"` instead of `username`.

So I tried this:

```
   print $user->field_first_name[und][0]['value'];
```

which is not printing anything  although the field `"First Name"` has some value.

Where am I going wrong ? Am I missing some obvious thing ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the global variable `$user`, it doesn't always contain a full initialized object. In fact, during the bootstrap, `$user` is initialized with the data contained in the "users" table, from the following code.

```
  if ($is_https) {
    $user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.ssid = :ssid", array(':ssid' => $sid))->fetchObject();
    if (!$user) {
      if (isset($_COOKIE[$insecure_session_name])) {
        $user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid AND s.uid = 0", array(
          ':sid' => $_COOKIE[$insecure_session_name],
        ))
        ->fetchObject();
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    $user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid", array(':sid' => $sid))->fetchObject();
  }

  // We found the client's session record and they are an authenticated,
  // active user.
  if ($user && $user->uid > 0 && $user->status == 1) {
    // This is done to unserialize the data member of $user.
    $user->data = unserialize($user->data);

    // Add roles element to $user.
    $user->roles = array();
    $user->roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID] = 'authenticated user';
    $user->roles += db_query("SELECT r.rid, r.name FROM {role} r INNER JOIN {users_roles} ur ON ur.rid = r.rid WHERE ur.uid = :uid", array(':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchAllKeyed(0, 1);
  }
```

If you want to be sure to get a fully loaded user object for the currently logged-in user, you should use the following code.

```
$account = user_uid_optional_load();
```

After that, you can get the value of any user field.

```
$fullname = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_first_name');
```

You can also get the rendered value of the field using the following code.

```
$rendered_value = field_view_field('user', $account, 'field_first_name');
```

The other reason for which `$user->field_first_name['und'][0]['value']` could not contain any value is that the language-neutral value of the field is not be set. (`'und'` is the value of the constant [LANGUAGE_NONE](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7), or [LANGUAGE_NOT_SPECIFIED](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NOT_SPECIFIED/8) in Drupal 8.) If you use [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), or [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7), you are sure to get the correct value.

As side note, it is preferable to keep the logic in the template.php file, in functions that are called from the template files.

Comment: Thank you @Kiamlaluno for the answer.                     I tried doing this: `$fullname = field_get_items('user', $user->uid, 'field_first_name');` in html.tpl  but did not get any value when I printed $fullname or $fullname['value'].

Comment: You need to pass the user object, not the user ID.

Comment: I tried without `uid` too, using simply `$user` but it also did not print anything.

Comment: And when I print `$user->field_first_name['und'][0]['value']` in `user-profile.tpl.php` it prints the value but it is not printing when used in `html.tpl.php`

Comment: How to you initialize the `$user` variable?

Comment: using 
       `global $user;`

Comment: The global `$user` is not always a fully user object. Only the values contained in the "users" table are initially used, and that table doesn't contain the values of the field API fields.

Comment: Thank you very much @kiamlaluno. It worked when I initialised $account and used it as you mentioned. And also thank you for explaining everything :)